# How do we know if a sensor value has been updated or not?

Tags: webots

Sensors are usually enabled with `wb_XXX_enable(tag, sampling_period)`, 
and the sensor values can be retrieved with `wb_XXX_get_values(tag)`.

How do we know if the values retrieved with `wb_XXX_get_values(tag)` are new values?

A naive approach would be saving the values and comparing it for every loop, but it won't work if the sensor values didn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you enable all your sensors at the first step of the controller (if it is not the case this method works also but is a bit more complex as you need to add an offset on the time for each sensor):

1. At each step, for each sensor, you can get the sampling period with the `period = wb_XXX_get_sampling_period(tag)`.
2. Then you can get the current simulation time and convert it to milliseconds: `int time = 1000 * wb_robot_get_time()`
3. Finally, you can compare the time with the sampling period of the sensor, if the modulo is 0, then it means the sensors was just updated: `bool updated = time % period == 0`.

Comment: It should be `wb_XXX_get_sampling_period(tag)` instead of `wb_XXX_et_sampling_period(tag)`